# Python: convert a 1-by-28-by-28 array to a 28-by-28 matrix

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib

I have a grayscale image stored as a 1-by-28-by-28 array (uint8) that I wish to display using matplotlib.

The relevant codes is as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

image = get_image()
print image.shape    # prints (1, 28, 28)
plt.imshow(image)
```

This code results in `TypeError: Invalid dimensions for image data`.

To be compatible with `imshow()` I need to either squeeze the array to be 28-by-28 (removing the redundant dimension) or replicate the 2D matrix (28-by-28) to 3 (RGB) or 4 (RGBA) channels.

My preference is to use the first approach, however `squeeze()` does not remove the redundant dimension.

How do I convert the 1-by-28-by-28 array into a 28-by-28 matrix?

Comment: `squeeze` returns the squeezed array, it doesn't modify the one you pass in

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass squeeze or reshape:

```
 imshow(np.squeeze(image))


 imshow(image.reshape((28,28))
```

Comment: Doesn't quite work if the image is 1-by-something or something-by-1, though.

Comment: You don't need the `squeeze` after using `reshape`.

Comment: @hpaulj,  yep,  that was a typo.

Answer (score 1):

```
image = image[0]
```

Pretty simple.